# No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000002

Tags: java, android, android-wallpaper

I am trying to retrieve current lock screen wallpaper but my app crashes.

```
 Drawable drawable = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getDrawable();
 getDrawable(WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
```

I am getting this error.

```
 No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000002
```